# Editing / reviewing - what's considered 'good form'?

Tags: discussion, review, edits

I'm seeing a number of edits recently where someone has put a comment into someone else's answer rather than using the standard 'comment' form. Is this acceptable? I want to flag and remove it, but it's happening enough that I'm here asking first.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1065622

Comment: Option number 2 on the rejection dialog: *This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.* The dialog acts as a guideline for what are *not* acceptable edits.

Comment: Worth noting the edit is from the question OP (but should still be a comment IMO)...

Comment: related, and possible dup: [Approving/rejecting edits made by the OP to an accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156306/182513)

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest an edit to your post that's actually just a comment

Comment: Unless the comment was a transfer from the actual comments associated with the answer (by the person doing the original answer), that is usually an invalid edit.  You can certainly mark it as such as you review.